# How do I fill in Dates in ts() function, when there is missing data for many months for over 2 years?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

Here is the data:

```
e <- data.frame( date = c("2016-03-08", "2016-05-19" ,"2016-05-19" ,"2016-09-02" ,"2016-09-02", "2016-11-23", "2016-12-29","2017-02-08" ,"2017-07-24", "2017-07-26" ,"2018-04-05" ,"2018-06-01", "2019-02-07" ,"2019-03-25"), price = c(1300, 1300, 1300 ,1300 ,1300 ,1300 ,1300 ,1300 ,1300 ,1300 ,1375 ,1375 ,1405 ,1405))

summary(e)
```

[image]

When I use ts(), I am not sure why the values are changing. Could someone explain?

```
b <- ts(e$price, start = c(2016,3), end = c(2019,3), frequency = 12)
```

Output: **Mar 2013** has the right price that is **1300**, but **Mar 2019** has the wrong value, it has **1300** instead of **1405**

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: The problem is, that your provided data do not correspond to each month. So April 2016 is not available and R starts from the beginning of the vector `e$price` when the end is reached to fill up every position.

Comment: @J_F What do I do is this situation, create random dates and assign NULL values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data does not represent a time series since mathematically a time series is a *function* from unique times to values.  Also `ts` does not handle daily data well.

If we omit all but the last data point in any year/month then we can convert it to a monthly `ts` series by reading it into a zoo series and in doing so converting the date column to `yearmon` class and aggregating on identical year/months using the last value.  Then convert that to `ts` class.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(e, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))
as.ts(z)
```

giving:

```
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
2016           1300   NA 1300   NA   NA   NA 1300   NA 1300 1300
2017   NA 1300   NA   NA   NA   NA 1300   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2018   NA   NA   NA 1375   NA 1375   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2019   NA 1405 1405
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Grothendieck, how does it treat multiple values for a month, does it take the average? in this example, "MAY 2016"

Comment: Thanks, did you get the variable x from the previous xts() edit?

Comment: how do I take the max value instead of aggregate, lets say, month april has 2 values 400,800. I want 800 to be selected instead of 400

Comment: `an1 <- read.zoo(temp8, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = max(x) tail(x,1))` gives me an error saying unexpected symbol